# How to edit email notification workflow in InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow, notifications

Is it possible to view or edit a workflow for email notifications only in InfoPath, and NOT with SharePoint Designer?

I have been asked to manage a SharePoint site that someone else built. It uses Forms built in InfoPath. I can open a list associated with email notifications in InfoPath, but I cannot view any part of the site (including this list) in SharePoint designer. I get the following error:

> Web Site Editing is Disabled. This site has been configured to
>   disallow editing with SharePoint Designer. Contact Your administrator.

I now am the administrator with admin access, and the person who built the site is gone. It is a SharePoint 2010 site. I've learned that our company does not allow production sites to be edited in Designer.

So how do I access the workflows to modify them?? Can it be done in just InfoPath??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot edit workflows using InfoPath. InfoPath is just for forms, either in Forms library or list forms. You would need to be able to open workflows in SharePoint designer to modify them, even if you are the admin of the site collection, farm admins can disable the option to edit the site in SharePoint Designer from Central Administration.